# I am not able to log in into a website using post requests python

Tags: python, post, urllib

I am trying to login into a website by passing username and password.It says session cookie is missing.I am beginner to api .I dont know if I have missed something here.The website is http://testing-ground.scraping.pro/login

```
 import urllib3
 http = urllib3.PoolManager()
 url = 'http://testing-ground.scraping.pro/login?mode=login'
 req = http.request('POST', url, fields={'usr':'admin','pwd':'12345'})
 print(req.data.decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Is that all the server returns? What do you understand from that message? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues in your code that make you unable to log in successfully.

## The content-type issue

In the code you are using `urllib3` to send data of content-type `multipart/form-data`. The website, however, seems to only accept the content-type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Try the following cURL commands:

1. `curl -v -d "usr=admin&pwd=12345" http://testing-ground.scraping.pro/login?mode=login`
2. `curl -v -F "usr=admin&pwd=12345" http://testing-ground.scraping.pro/login?mode=login`

For the first one, the content-type in your request header is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, so the website takes it and logs you in (with a `302 Found` response).

The second one, however, sends data with content-type `multipart/form-data`. The website doesn't take it and therefore rejects your login request (with a `200 OK` response).

## The cookie issue

Another issue is that `urllib3` follows redirect by default. More importantly, the cookie is not handled (i.e. stored and sent in the following requests) by default by `urllib3`. Thus, the second request won't contain the cookie `tdsess=TEST_DRIVE_SESSION`, and therefore the website returns the message that you're not logged in.

If you only care about the login request, you can try the following code:

```
import urllib3

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
url = 'http://testing-ground.scraping.pro/login?mode=login'
req = http.request('POST', url, data={'usr':'admin','pwd':'12345'}, encode_multipart=False, redirect=False)
print(req.data.decode('utf-8'))
```

The `encode_multipart=False` instructs `urllib3` to send data with content-type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`; the `redirect=False` tells it not to follow the redirect, so that you can see the response of your initial request.

If you do want to complete the whole login process, however, you need to save the cookie from the first response and send it in the second request. You can do it with `urllib3`, or

## Use the Requests library

I'm not sure if you have any particular reasons to use `urllib3`. `Urllib3` will definitely work if you implements it well, but I would suggest try the [`Request`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) library, which is much easier to use. For you case, the following code with `Request` will work and get you to the welcome page:

```
import requests

url = 'http://testing-ground.scraping.pro/login?mode=login'
req = requests.post(url, data={'usr':'admin','pwd':'12345'})
print(req.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests

auth_credentials = ("admin", "12345")
url = "http://testing-ground.scraping.pro/login?mode=login"
response = requests.post(url=url, auth=auth_credentials)
print(response.text)
```